# Why is it recommended to call MultiDex.install() in attachBaseContext(Context)?

Tags: java, android

I am learning multiDex in android platform. Here is https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html#mdex-gradle.
When I use multiDex support library, the output apk will contain multi dex files such as class.dex, class1.dex, class2.dex. Then I write a class named `myApplication` inherited from `Application` and override the api `attachBaseContext`. In the method, I call `MultiDex.install()` just as recommended.

My question is that what would happen if I used `MultiDex.install()` in `onCreate`?

I know `attachBaseContext` is called before `onCreate`, so called in `attachBaseContext` is better.Howerver, actually I want to know is that why is it recommended just here? Is it a situation that `ClassNotFoundException` is threw when I call it in onCreate?